# Do I need to forward a port for my friend to join me in Minecraft Bedrock over the Internet?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I understand that for Minecraft Java edition, I'd need to forward some port from my router in order for my friend to connect to me. Is this also true for Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

I start a game by opening a single-player world and inviting her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Bedrock edition, multiplayer is actually rather well intergrated. Since the better together update, you can play with your friends really easily.

All you need are separate Microsoft accounts, both having separate license. Then, you can add each other as a friend through the Xbox platform, wether that be on an Xbox, on the Xbox app, on right from in Minecraft Bedrock, under the "Friends" tab.

Once you have each other friended, its as simple as one friend joining the others game through the "Friends" tab.

If this isnt working: make sure your games' settings don't prohibit multiplayer (game, settings, multiplayer) and make sure that your microsoft settings don't prohibit multiplayer.